# What is "cum supportatione"?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, medieval-latin

In *Epistolae obscurorum virorum*, [letter 3](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/Chronologia/Lspost16/ViriObscuri/vir_1503.html):

> 'Mus miser est antro qui solum clauditur uno.’ Sic etiam possum dicere de me **cum supportatione**, venerabilis vir, quia essem pauper si haberem tantum unum amicum, et quando ille unus **superdaret** me, tunc non haberem alium, qui me **traetaret** amicabiliter.

My attempt:

> 'Wretch is the mouse who is closed only by one hollow'. I can say so also about myself, ???, you honored man, for I would be poor if I had only one friend; and when that one left(?) me, then I would have no other who would treat me friendly (?)

The words in bold I could not find in dictionary and probably medieval, but I think I could get their sense, except *cum supportatione* which still evades me (with carry/endurance) - but how it fits the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Du Cange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/SUPPORTARE1#SUPPORTARE1-3) defines *supportatio* as "Defensio, tuitio, protectio". *Justification* would seem to work as a translation in this context.